# Load live image into JLabel not working for some urls

Tags: java, image, swing, url

I want to **load the live URL image into JLabel**.
I have tried the code, but it did not work for some URLs.
Don't know what happen? **Exception also not occur.**

```
    try {
        String imageUrl = "https://www.mouser.com/images/molex/images/501331-001a.jpg"; // not working url
       // String imageUrl = "http://in.element14.com/productimages/standard/en_GB//1458900-40.jpg"; // not working url
       // String imageUrl = "https://euroc-static.s3.amazonaws.com/verifiedcomp/pkg_files/parts_files/63661/63661.jpg"; // working url   
    
       URL url = new URL(imageUrl);     
       Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(300, 300);
       JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
       frame.add(label);
       frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Bhavin S. Look for my edited answer, it should solve your problem

Comment: @Szprota21 Cudos to your effort... Your code is working fine in Java11. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that i did help you. But you probably should change title of that post. Maybe it will help someone later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Working solution here** (it's only since Java 11 for older versions you will need to find different rest framework)

Also in this image "in.element14" you should have https protocol.

It wasn't working because of returning content length was negative. It appears that HttpUrlConnection doesn't support that case.

**@Andrew Thompson no conversion was needed...**

```
private void initUI() {
        JPanel images = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(images, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        images.setLayout(boxLayout);
        images.setVisible(true);
        images.add(testLabel(
                "https://imageproxy.themaven.net//https%3A%2F%2Fwww.history.com%2F.image%2FMTY4OTA4MzI0ODc4NjkwMDAw%2Fchristmas-tree-gettyimages-1072744106.jpg"));
        images.add(testLabel("https://www.mouser.com/images/molex/images/501331-001a.jpg"));
        images.add(testLabel("https://euroc-static.s3.amazonaws.com/verifiedcomp/pkg_files/parts_files/63661/63661.jpg"));
        images.add(testLabel("https://in.element14.com/productimages/standard/en_GB/1458900-40.jpg"));
        this.add(images);
}

private JPanel testLabel(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                             .uri(URI.create(imageUrl)).GET()
                                             .build();
            HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request,
                                                        responseInfo -> HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofByteArray());
            InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body());
            Image image = ImageIO.read(targetStream);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            panel.add(label);
            panel.setVisible(true);
            return panel;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setSize(300, 300);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading failed");
            panel.add(label);
            panel.setVisible(true);
            return panel;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out .

```
      // String imageURL="https://imageproxy.themaven.net//https%3A%2F%2Fwww.history.com%2F.image%2FMTY4OTA4MzI0ODc4NjkwMDAw%2Fchristmas-tree-gettyimages-1072744106.jpg";
       String imageUrl = "https://www.mouser.com/images/molex/images/501331-001a.jpg"; // not working url
       // String imageUrl = "http://in.element14.com/productimages/standard/en_GB//1458900-40.jpg"; // not working url
       // String imageUrl = "https://euroc-static.s3.amazonaws.com/verifiedcomp/pkg_files/parts_files/63661/63661.jpg"; // working url   
    
        Image image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel Panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        Panel.add(label);
        frame.add(Panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

This should work perfectly

Comment: you basically did paste the same code as OP. And it won't work because it hangs on ImageIO.read, it's probably a server/proxy issue

Comment: No I tried it ,it would return nullpointerexception or some error when it doesn't get the image

Comment: I did copy paste your code and it hangs up on read

Comment: I am checking if it is a issue with url .

Comment: If you try to get image like this:

```URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
Image image = ImageIO.read(is);```

Then you will get read timeout after 5 sec

Comment: Try it once now , I edited the code @Szprota21

Comment: still not working, you didn't change anything relevant

Comment: @ProgrammingGeek The problem with Bhavin is he is facing a problem with the particular URLs to load image in Jlabel. like he has shared  http://in.element14.com/productimages/standard/en_GB//1458900-40.jpg . try this url to solve his query. else his code is also working for the url that you have used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure

```
// String imageUrl = "http://in.element14.com/productimages/standard/en_GB//1458900-40.jpg";
```

this URL not working. I doubt that is an SSL problem. It means that you can not access the startWith 'https://' URL of images.

Comment: Ok, That is right. It is the same result when I test it. And yet, I find out the problem you can consider. This happens only if the URL being passed is secure (that is, HTTPS), and in the case of HTTP URLs, it works as expected.

Comment: Solutions: www.mouser.com ; Put certificate into your AEM server truststore. It means the problem comes from imageUrl, not your code. if you want to access this URL, you should admit by the URL server.

Comment: I confirm another url address, that is right in this case. Such as my company goodsImages below:
`https://facebook-dev.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com//20210105/10c617f99a3c42bf83982a58d208bcfb.png`

Comment: *"It means that you can not access the startWith 'https://' URL"* The last image, which is commented as `// working url` ***is an*** HTTPS URL.